# Сервер node js на VPS c https

Tags: node.js, nginx, https, vps

Хочу поставить сервер node на хостинг VPS. У меня нет рут прав, проксирование и тд  делается через тех поддержку. Так же мой провайдер автматически выдает сертификат ssl Lets Encrypt и подключает его если сервер на пхп. Для ноды я написал сервер так:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Настройка сервера Express
const options = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./sslcert/fullchain.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('./sslcert/privkey.pem')
};

app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.render('index', data);
  });

https.createServer(options, app).listen(8082);
```

И попросил ключ и сертификат для размещения в своей директории.

Их ответ: "Уберите пожалуйста пути к сертификату с сервера ноды, https будет отдавать nginx и проксировать всё на localhost:8082".
Я теперь не понимаю сервер будет работать просто в таком варианте?:

```
https.createServer(app).listen(8082);
```

или даже так?

```
app.listen(8082);
```

Локально никакой вариант не работает.

Comment: В ноде ssl действительно нафиг не нужен, всё делается на уровне nginx

Comment: "Локально никакой вариант не работает." Вы HTTPS проверяете? Тогда это нормально, что HTTPS не работает, он и не должен. Работать должен HTTP. А HTTPS займётся уже nginx, как вам и сказали в поддержке.

Comment: Да при http локально все работает. Просто я сейчас пробую и через обычный app.listen(8082); мне приходит ответ Forbidden, ну может они там еще не все настроили и пока жду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будет работать и локально

> http://localhost:8082

```
app.listen(8082);
```

А для SSL настройте  nginx темболие статику все равно лутше через него отдавать так как в доке самого express написано что они не рекомендуют отдавать статику через них

```
# nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default 
   .....
    location /{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8082/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
  .......
```

а  уже  в nginx поставите сертификат но  важно proxy_pass оставляйте http://localhost8082/

а там уже сконфигурируете nginx на ssl и все будет у вас работать на лайве https на  локале без

Comment: К настройкам nginx у меня тоже доступа нет( Буду надеятся, что они сами все правильно настроят. Спасибо за помощь. Протестирую, если заработает, отмечу как правильное решение.